trying to use Google Appscript to create a slide presentation from the data in a specific sheet. error TypeError: ss.getSheetById is not a function
Here is my code:and I keep getting the error message "TypeError: ss.getSheetById is not a function
I originally had a try catch block but when I had that in, the error messages kept popping up as error: _______. There was nothing after the colon, after getting rid of the try catch block, now I get the error message stated earlier.
  const spreadsheetId = '1z1HAUVNnoAtMUa4DtlcbJ21EPBHfHrAFEF4a9XsRgMA';
  const sheetID = 0;

  // Ensure correct import
  SpreadsheetApp;

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);

  if (!ss) {
    Logger.log("Error: Could not open spreadsheet.");
    return;
  }

  const sheet = ss.getSheetById(sheetID);

  // Access data from the sheet (example: get the value in cell A1)
  const cellValue = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log("Value in cell A1:", cellValue);

  // Create a new presentation based on data from the sheet
  const presentation = SlidesApp.create("Test Presentation");
  const slide = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.TITLE_AND_BODY);

  // Add content to the slide based on the sheet data
  const title = slide.getPageElements().find(element => element.getType() === SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE);
  title.insertText(0, "Data from Sheet A1: " + cellValue);

  Logger.log("Presentation created successfully!");
}




There is no getSheetById function. There is only getSheetByName.

Based on this Issue Tracker that was posted last 2014, the getSheetById feature is not yet implemented and the status of the request is still assigned.  As @PatrickdC said, you may use getSheetByName instead.

Thank you! I was able to get through the error messages. I'm sure I'll be posting on here again for when I actually input the specific information from the sheet and try to format it.

I'll go ahead and post my initial comment as an answer to your question since getSheetById is a feature that is not yet implemented.

You're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer

getSheetById Feature Not Yet Implemented
Based from the Class Spreadsheet article, getSheetById does not exist.
On the other hand, there is an Issue Tracker that was posted on 2014, getSheetById feature is not yet implemented. The request's status is still assigned.
For the meantime, you may use getSheetByName. You may use this function as follows:
SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet_ID").getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");

References:

getSheetByName
Issue Tracker: getSheetById method needed in spreadsheet app
openById

